# python connecting to Azure database

Tags: python, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-functions

I am connecting Azure database from python. while doing I have to pass below parameters. What I have to specify in the 'driver' as string.

```
enter code here

server = '<server>.database.windows.net'
database = '<database>'
username = '<username>'
password = '<password>'
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 20 pc.Name as CategoryName, p.name as ProductName FROM [SalesLT]. 
[ProductCategory] pc JOIN [SalesLT].[Product] p ON pc.productcategoryid = p.productcategoryid")
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row:
print (str(row[0]) + " " + str(row[1]))
row = cursor.fetchone()
```

Comment: The information which you provided is not clear.

Comment: I am trying to connect Azure database using python.. I am not sure what to be given in the driver string..

Comment: import logging
import pyodbc

import azure.functions as func


print(4*5)

server = '<server>.database.windows.net'
database = '<database>'
username = '<username>'
password = '<password>'
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)

cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 20 Name as Name,TableAId as ID FROM [dbo].[TableA]")
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row:
    print (str(row[0]) + " " + str(row[1]))
    row = cursor.fetchone()

Comment: It depends on the driver version you installed on your environment.

Comment: I am connecting to Azure and below string is working..pyodbc.connect( 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + database + ';UID=' + username + ';Authentication=ActiveDirectoryInteractive;') cursor = conn.cursor() with ;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryInteractive, system ask for password. How can I avoid asking password in Azure. Any iead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 on your environment. Then the value for driver should be `driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'`. You can download different ODBC drivers [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15).

The working python samle:

```
    import pyodbc
    server = 'test.database.windows.net'
    database = ''
    username = ''
    password = ''
    driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server +
                      ';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';Uid=testsql;Pwd={your_password_here};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30')
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
        "select * from Persons")
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    while row:
        print(str(row[0]) + " " + str(row[1]))
        row = cursor.fetchone()
```

Comment: I am connecting to Azure and below string is working..pyodbc.connect(
    'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + database + ';UID=' + username + ';Authentication=ActiveDirectoryInteractive;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
with ;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryInteractive, system ask for password. How can I avoid asking password in Azure. Any iead

Comment: @Andrew Yes, you will be asked for password. You can also use Active Directory password authentication. `Authentication=Active Directory Password; Initial Catalog=testdb;  UID=bob@contoso.onmicrosoft.com; PWD=MyPassWord!`

Comment: @Andrew You want to use Azure AD authentication without providing pwd?